# Restoring lost icons

Tags: macos

I recently installed Yosemite on my MacBook Air. I note that my Reading List items no longer display the icon/logo from the web pages. They were very handy for quickly locating the item I was looking for without having to read through all the text. Is there a way to restore them?

Answer (score 1):

Lets try following to restore your old reading list:

Quit Safari. In the Finder, hold down the option key and select

> Go > Library

from the menu bar.

The reading list is stored in the file Safari/Bookmarks.plist in the Library folder.

You have two choices:

Restore the file from a **backup** that predates the issue; or

Move the file to the Desktop, relaunch Safari, and import from the old bookmarks file (File > Import Bookmarks...).

Comment: Eek! Not sure what I did wrong. History folder has now disappeared. plist file is on the desktop but after trying to import it, I get the message there is no reading list. If I try to start a new reading list, no icons come with the web references so the original problem remains. Sigh.

Comment: I did not say anything about delete. Do you or do you not have a back up ? If you moved it to the desktop and it is not working move it back.